# How to use NSPredicate to find an NSString begins with numbers or special characters in ios?

Tags: ios, nspredicate

Could you please help, how to use NSPredicate to find an NSString beginsWith numbers or other special characters (But not begin with alphabets)? I want to sort an array name that contains any numbers and special characters. Advance thanks for help.

Comment: NSDiacriticInsensitivePredicateOption can be used for filtering special characters

Comment: `@"SELF MATCHES %@",@"[^a-zA-Z0-9]+.*"` ?

Comment: Thanks larme. Its worked for me. Mistake i had done is not including "+.". I had used as "[^A-Za-z]*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the `MATCHES` keyword:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithString:@"self MATCHES [^a-zA-Z]+.*"]
```

You can find more docu here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-215868

and the definition of how to define the regex here:

http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp